# Should I create a Controller or just a class if Model is accessed but not view is involved?

Tags: php, laravel, separation-of-concerns

I am building an invoicing app with Laravel. *Invoices* consist (among other things) of one or many *Items* (invoice lines).

*Invoice* and invoice *Items* have separate database tables and models. However, *Items* are created together with their parent *Invoice*, in the same form and view.

So, views and controller make sense for Invoice... but what about Items? Where should I place all my logic processing the form, displaying errors or whatever related to Items? In the same InvoiceController, in a separate class...?

Sorry if this is a repeated question, I've tried to find an answer without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be logical to include all your processing for invoice items within a invoice controller. In the MVC pattern it is not necessary to have a controller and view specific for each of your models. This would be an anti-pattern.